# What are the Correct pronunciations for "Wednesday" and "pizza"?

Tags: pronunciation

Most people do not pronounce the `d` in "Wednesday" but many times on the radio or TV I hear them pronounce the `d` slightly (so that everyone can hear it). Is this correct, either in American or British accents?

I'm also curious about "pizza". I know it's an Italian word but in English how should it be pronounced? Some people add an extra `t` in the middle but someone pronounce it as it's written.

Comment: You can go to www.forvo.com to listen to recordings of people from all over the world pronouncing different words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Wednesday** - I've always remembered how to *spell* this by saying WED NES DAY or "WEDDING'S DAY", but it's primarily pronounced *wenz day* or *wenz dee*. I searched several references, and found only a ***small set*** of people who include the "wed" sound, saying "wednz day":

- **IPA:** [/ˈwɛnzˌdeɪ/](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/Wednesday) (AmE) [/ˈwɛnzdeɪ/](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/Wednesday) (BrE)
- http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/Wednesday?q=wednesday has an AmE say "wenz day" or "wenz dee".
- http://www.forvo.com/word/wednesday/#en (Note that of all sample pronunciations, at this time only one, by *TopQuark (Male from United Kingdom)*, says "Wednz day".
- http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=wednesday&submit=Submit has an BrE speaker suggest either "wenz day" or "wednz day"
  -

**Pizza** Most Americans pronounce it like "**Pete's a** good guy" or technically:

- **IPA:** [/ˈpitsə/](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/pizza) (AmE) [/ˈpiːtsə/](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pizza) (BrE)

Some people might say ***pee zza*** because that's how it looks or their parents  and friends said it or they think it sounds Italian (it doesn't).

When it comes to **radio shows**, announcers are trained to enunciate, over-pronounce, or stress words in special ways that emphasize clarity over absolute correctness; it might not even be precisely the correct pronunciation. So if you listen to radio announcers, you can sometimes hear non-typical pronunciations.

---

Information on pronunciation of minestrone has been moved here: [How do you pronounce, "minestrone"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28908/how-do-you-pronounce-minestrone/28909#28909)

Comment: +1 for "When it comes to radio shows, announcers are trained to enunciate, over-pronounce, or stress words in special ways that emphasize clarity over absolute correctness; it might not even be precisely the correct pronunciation. So if you listen to radio announcers, you can sometimes hear non-typical pronunciations."

Comment: I can only speak from personal experience about "wednz day" (I'm English), but I'm considered mildly eccentric by friends and colleagues for pronouncing it that way. I'm fine with that.

Comment: I didn't know that _wenz dee_ was a possibility. I'll have to start listening for that. Does the _-dee_ apply to other days of the week?

Comment: Everything is correct here except your IPA transcriptions. You want the /ɛ/ phoneme for the first vowel, in AmE at least. @user6951, yes, the -i pronunciation is optional for all days of the week, although it sounds a bit dated to me.

Answer (score 2):

In re: "Pizza"

American English: "PEET-za".  Always.

Answer (score 2):

I have always pronounced Pizza and Wednesday as /pitsə/ and /wendzde/ with /ts/ and /dz/ representing the affricate sounds. The pizza pronunciation is normal, but the Wednesday pronunciation probably isn't. The differences probably are 1) using an alveolar affricate instead of as the alveolar sibilant 2) pronouncing the long a sound as a pure /e/ instead of the diphthong /eɪ/

Comment: I agree with the ndzd consonant cluster and was glad someone else had it too!

Answer (score 0):

Pizza: /ˈpiːtsə/ ____ Wednesday:/ˈwenzdeɪ/ and /ˈwenzdi/