# How do you pronounce, "minestrone"?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letter

How should one pronounce, "minestrone" in English?  I was at an Italian restaurant (US) and ordered "min eh stron ee soup" and my friend told me that's wrong... that the ending "e" is silent.  They said it's pronounced, "min e stron".  What is correct?

Comment: Wouldn't a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/minestrone) be able to settle this debate?

Comment: I think that most dictionaries actually fail to describe the variation that CoolHandLouis asks about in his question and talks about in his answer.  I think this question adds something useful to the site that you wouldn't get from a dictionary lookup alone, so I'd like to keep this question open.

Comment: @snailplane Even if they did, would that merit closing this? This addresses a common-enough, mistaken, prescriptive pronunciation (multiple people have told me the "correct" pronunciation).  Even if all dictionaries included an IPA on this tomorrow, the problem this Q/A addresses would still exist.  OTOH, I noticed maybe there's a clean up effort on ELL?  Tightening ship?

Answer (score 7):

*Ministrone* is an English loan word from Italian.  Italian language courses teach the Standard Italian pronunciation in which almost all letters are vocalized except silent h.  (So for example, "bella" is pronounced "bel la", not "be la".) So *minestrone* is pronounced ["min eh stron ee"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQae1J8FnNo) or ["min eh stron eh"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGMoixDg9s4).

However, many people in America pronounce it "ministrohn" (silent e), and this is also ok, as that's how it's pronounced in some Italian dialects.  In fact, this type of pronunciation (dropping ending vowels, especially for foods) was popularized during the long running HBO series, "The Sopranos".  (See [Why do The Sopranos leave off the last vowel in Italian words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182270/why-do-the-sopranos-leave-off-the-last-vowel-in-italian-words))

But those who insist that  "ministrohn" is the *only* proper pronunciation don't know what they're talking about.  From a linguistic perspective, neither pronunciation is "the one and only correct way" or "wrong", they're just different.

---

Here's a good article from the The New York Times:  [You Say Prosciutto, I Say Pro-SHOOT, and Purists Cringe](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/09/20/nyregion/you-say-prosciutto-i-say-proshoot-and-purists-cringe.html).

For general reference, see [Italian drop final vowel](https://www.google.com/search?q=italian+drop+final+vowel).

Search keyword: minestrone soup

Comment: The question is about how to pronounce it in English, not in Italian.

Comment: @sumelic I asked the question!  I provided this question/answer as a reference because the question sometimes pops up among English speakers.

Comment: In [Genovese dialect](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minestrone_alla_genovese) (Italy) it is commonly called ***menestrun***...

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks!  I've made some updates to the answer, which I think better reflects the point about the impact of native regional dialects on American pronunciation.

Comment: There's also some variation on the second syllable. According to the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary, some people pronounce the second syllable /ɪ/ rather than /ə/.

Answer (score 0):

In AmE, there seems to be different  ways of pronouncing it

> [minestrone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtWNUAUmGpU&t=0m11s)

and

> [minestron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4U170ZXy54&t=0m19s)
>   (she has an Italian surname...)

Maybe it's a [potato/tomato thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZ3fjQa5Hls&t=1m30s) especially if it has different pronunciations in Italian.